# Deleting columns with rows values from data table

Tags: c#, windows, gridview

I want to delete specific column from my datable before bounding it to a grid view.
I tried with

```
finalTable.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
finalTable.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
```

but it does not delete rows values belonging to that column..

How can we delete column with row values??

EDIT: After bounding it to gridview rows are displayed in 3rd column.

Comment: How do you say your row values are not deleted? Are you able to access them after deletion?

Comment: Are you using GridView1.DataSource = finalTable?

Comment: Did any of our answers resolve the issue you were having?

Answer (score 1):

give this a try:

```
 DataTable example; 
       example.Columns.Remove("columnName"); 
       example.Columns.RemoveAt(columnIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If(finalTable.Columns.CanRemove(finalTable.Columns[0]))
{
    finalTable.Columns.RemoveAt(0); 
}

finalTable.AcceptChanges()
```

Then bind it with your gridview